# Вычислить конечную цифру файла, и создать новый файл

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, в PHP всего 3 дня, пишу базу под iOS устройство, знаю только Objective-C, так что прошу не критиковать меня в нубстве.

И так, вопрос знатокам:

> Нужен php код, который будет смотреть
> папку "users/", (в которой находятся
> файлы: 1.php, 2.php, 3.php и т.д), и
> отслеживать конечный файл, в данном
> случае 3.php, и создавать - 4.php
> через fopen.

Можно пожалуйста код, или объяснение как написать такой..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам, очевидно, нужна база данных, но если хотите именно таким путем, то

```
$dir = 'users';
$files = scandir($dir); // получаем список всех файлов
$maxId = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $id = (int)$file;
    if ($id === 0) { // отсеиваем те файлы, которые не начинаются с числа (а это, как минимум, '..' и '.'
        continue;
    } else if ($maxId < $id) {
        $maxId = $Id; // записываем максимальный айдишник
    }
}
$filename = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.($maxId + 1).'.php'; // формируем имя файла, прибавляя к максимальному айди 1
$fileHandle = fopen($filename, 'w');
```

Вообще там есть более умный подход, но мне сейчас надо бежать.

Comment: Спасибо, ну вообще я бы хотел создать через мускул, но то, для чего делаю, не стоит этого) Спасибо большое)

Comment: $maxId = 0;, не хочет записывать максимальный айди, поэтому прибавляет напрямую к нулю, как решить?

Comment: Id было вместо id, при записи максимального ID, всё отлично работает. Спасиб